# Use a pre-compiler before regular compile with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

I need to write a script as a pre-compiler for Visual Studio 2015 C. The script will just replace some GNU directives with the blanks. I remember seeing that once in earlier versions of VS but can't find it in 2015 ... maybe I'm just looking at the wrong options.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Sounds like the wrong solution, perhaps you can just use the preprocessor instead? Or is the code "read-only?"

Answer (score 0):

You can name a [Forced Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c5ztk84.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) file to be included at the beginning of every C++ source file.

In this include file, you can define macros for all your desired global replacements. This should be far easier than to write your own preprocessor filter.

Comment: That is not what I want to do. The change I need to make is to remove some GNU __attribute__ statements on structures. A #define does not work for that.

Comment: It might help to actually see an example for what you want to achieve.

Comment: I don't see an example. The GNU attribute cannot be #defined to be something different (specifically to replace "struct S { short f[3]; } __attribute__ ((aligned (8)));" with "struct S { short f[3]; };". If you can do it then please give me the proper #define.